# Pixi sound continuous play on page navigation & control panel addition

Tags: javascript, audio, local-storage, pixi.js

I've been trying to add a continuously playing audio to a web page using pixi sound. My problem is that when I navigate to another page on a website the audio starts from the beginning every single time, but I want it to start from where it ended before I navigated to another page (so basically to play continuously).

My code:

```
<button class="btn1 btn-lg off" id="paused">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pause off"></span>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play on"></span>
</button>
```

As for the script:

```
PIXI.sound.Sound.from({
url: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0562/5846/1760/files/Rimzee_-_Intro_Official_Audio.mp3?v=1676663051',
volume: 0.1,
preload: true,
loaded: function(err, sound) {
    const instance = sound.play();
    instance.on('progress', function(progress) {
        console.log('Amount played: ', progress * 100 + 'seconds');
      localStorage.setItem("current-progress",progress * 100);
    });
    sound.play({
        volume: 0.1,
        start: localStorage.getItem("current-progress"),
        end: 106,
    });
  }
});
console.log(localStorage.getItem("current-progress"))
```

What I'm trying is save the current progress of the song to local storage then use that value as the starting point for the audio, but it doesn't seem to work.

Another thing I was trying is to add a control panel for the audio, but I couldn't make it. Can anyone please help out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is essentially correct, but there are a couple of minor issues when retrieving the data from `localStorage`:

If you look at the documentation about [localStorage.getItem()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) you'll find that it always returns a string or null if the value doesn't exist. Regardless if you save the sound progress as a number, it will be stringified before it gets stored.

This doesn't only mean that the value has to be parsed to number before you can actually provide it to the `play` method, but you also need to handle the scenario where `null` is returned.

```js
PIXI.sound.Sound.from({
  url: "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0562/5846/1760/files/Rimzee_-_Intro_Official_Audio.mp3?v=1676663051",
  volume: 1,
  preload: true,
  loaded: function (err, sound) {
    const startTime = parseFloat(localStorage.getItem("current-progress"));
    
    const instance = sound.play({
      volume: 1,
      // Make sure that a valid numeric value has been received
      start: Number.isFinite(startTime) ? startTime : 0,
      end: 106
    });
    
    instance.on("progress", function (progress) {
      localStorage.setItem("current-progress", progress * 100);
    });
  }
});
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/epaezrubio/pen/qBMqRyx?) is a working Codepen.

Also keep in mind that if the audio is played all the way to the end, the start time will actually be the end time and the audio will end as soon as it starts. Make sure that you're also handling that scenario.

Comment: Hi there,
Thank you this is working as wonders and also thank you for the quick explanation about the minor error why it wasn't working previously.

Do you know how can we add the control panel for the audio as well so it can be paused and played freely?

Comment: Add the div and spans in your HTML register the corresponding "click" listeners with `addEventListener`.